# confused between work on /work for/work against/work to

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

> whatever the tactic we had, just didn't **work for** them.

context: yesterday Barcelona lost to Liverpool 0-4.

I'm speaking as a Barcelona fan.
I'm not sure what preposition should be followed after "work".

what I want to mean is that our tactic didn't seem effective against Liverpool

Comment: So in this context "we" is the Barcelona team and "them" is the Liverpool team?

Comment: To make this even more confusing, I would have used *"work **with**"* in this context.

Comment: @Mixolydian yes you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the prepositions (that follows **work**) constructs a different **phrasal verb** with a particular meaning.

Taking them in the order you give them:

**..to work on...** means to be labouring on, occupied with, busy with etc. It is also used in expressions such as **to work on site** or **....to work on time**.

**..to work for...** can mean either **to be employed by (somebody/a company)...** or **to work in the favour of/to assist**. In this sense, none of the tactics that Barcelona tried assisted them/worked in their favour/helped them to succeed.

**..to work against ...** has the opposite meaning of opposing/hindering a person or enterprise.

**..to work to...** is used in certain expressions such as **to work to rule**, meaning to stick to every little rule and not to be flexible. It is also widely used as an infinitive, as in **went to work to finish the job**.